# CSS keyframes animations with no delays between iterations

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make an animation loop with keyframes but there's an unwanted delay before the animation starts and also between the iterations. I can't set the animation end to 100 % because it doesn't start then. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.first {
height: 100vh;
perspective: 900px; }
  
.second{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 200%;
transform: rotateX(70deg) translateX(-10%) translateY(50%);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 1;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FE18D3 0%, #333  0.10% 1.90%, #FE18D3 2%);
background-size: 100vw 100vw;
animation-name: gradient;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
        
@keyframes gradient {
  0% { background-position: 0%; }
  50% { background-position: 100%; }
}
        
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="first">
<div class="second"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want - do you or don't you want a delay between each iteration? BTW you are missing a closing curly brace at the end of the keyframes.

Comment: I want no delay between the iterations. And it should start without delay. (Thanks for mentioning the closing curly. I removed some things before pasting the code)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: The initial answer suffered from two problems - in particular there was 100% usage of the GPU (which meant that at times there wasn't enough processor power to do what was required).

This led to thinking of a different way of doing the animation. This snippet puts the background image onto a before pseudo element and translates that rather than requiring the system to recalculate from scratch the repeating background image. The GPU usage (on my Windows 10 laptop) is still high (around 60%) but at least there is enough processor power to keep things going.

The pseudo element is twice the height of its 'owner' and it animates just to 50% of its height and then starts again, that way things are smooth.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .first {
      height: 100vh;
      perspective: 900px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .second {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15%;
      /* this amount depends on the angle of rotation so may need recalculating */
      left: 0;
      width: 200vw;
      height: 100vh;
      transform: rotateX(70deg) translateX(-30%);
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      margin: 0 auto;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .second::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FE18D3 0% 5%, #333 5% 100%);
      background-size: 100% 5%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat repeat;
      background-position: left top;
      animation-name: gradient;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes gradient {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="first">
    <div class="second"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

This is a partial answer in the hope it will lead to a full one.

To remove the delay at the start you can set the animation-delay to -5s - ie. start off at the middle of the animation.

To remove the pauses during the infinite animation you can add another copy of the element and animate that during the pauses of the first.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .first {
      height: 100vh;
      perspective: 900px;
    }
    
    .second,
    .third {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      rright: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 200%;
      transform: rotateX(70deg) translateX(-10%) translateY(50%);
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      margin: 0 auto;
      z-index: 1;
      background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FE18D3 0%, #333 0.10% 1.90%, #FE18D3 2%);
      background-size: 100vw 100vw;
      animation-name: gradient;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .second {
      animation-delay: -5s;
    }
    
    @keyframes gradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0%;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      50% {
        background-position: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      50.0000001% {
        background-position: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="first">
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

There are a couple of problems with this though. The most obvious is that there is a slight jerk every 5 seconds as the timing/positioning is not exact (?)

The other problem is that a huge amount of processor time is taken up. On my fairly powerful laptop the GPU usage ranges between 99% and 100% - which probably means that it's not quite keeping up on occasion. [and maybe a contributing factor to the jerkiness??]. It's also a battery-flattener which users may not appreciate.

It may be worth exploring a different method of animation, for example translations so the system doesn't have to constantly calculate positioning of a repeating background image.

Comment: What's the reason for the delay at the start?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi as the OP mentioned in the question, if you go to 100% actually the pattern is in the same place, so nothing happens as far as the viewer can tell. The animation isn't actually delayed, it takes place but it's just that for the first 50% it didn't make any difference visually.